# Fragment's BroadcastReceiver onCreate method does not get called

Tags: android, android-fragments, bluetooth, android-broadcast, localbroadcastmanager

I have a simple Fragment within my Activity in which I enable and disable Bluetooth adapter and I want to listen to Bluetooth Adapter state changes with a BroadcastReceiver from within the Fragment. The reason is that I want to directly change the Fragment's UI elements upon Bluetooth state change. This is my code:

```
public class FragmentBT extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(BtStateChangedReceiver, iFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(BtStateChangedReceiver);
    }

    public BroadcastReceiver BtStateChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            ... change UI based on the extra data from intent ...
        }
    }
}
```

When I enable or disable BT in my device using Action Buttons in my Fragment's ActionBar, the BT goes on and off, but my receiver never gets called. I never get into the receiver's onReceive method. I realize this is a pretty common question here, but I tried the sollutions from several but neither worked (and all are incorporated into my current code).

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: I hope you have already defined <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> permission in your menifest.

Comment: Bhavesh: Yes, I have both BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions. Mateus: I'm not. I am only listenning to the broadcast. I assume the BT state changed broadcast is sent by the system, It wouldn't make much sense listening to it otherwise, am I wrong?

Comment: It's because of trickery like this that I try to put my receivers in the manifest whenever possible.

Comment: e4c5: Normaly I do too, but this way I can very easily acces the Fragment's UI. If I declared my Receiver in a separate class and put it into a manifest, I know of no easy way of doing that. This approach seems very elegant to me and I'd really like it to be working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(BtStateChangedReceiver, iFilter);
getActivity().unregisterReceiver(BtStateChangedReceiver);
```

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) say that 'LocalBroadcastManager' is used to 'register for and send broadcasts of Intents to local objects within your process'.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the problem. I also noticed that about the LocalBroadcastManager. I used a workaround using a BroadcastReceiver registered in manifest and declared in a separate class. In that I parse the Intent's data and than propagate the Broadcast further into my application using the sendBroadcast method of the LocalBroadcastManager. Than the Broadcast is finaly received by my BtStateChangedReceiver (in the code I posted.). Anyway, thanks for a helpful tip!